# How to scroll to the bottom of this list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, scrolling

I've gone to this page:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active

...and I clicked the 'more sites' link. However, there's no scrollbar in the list so it's impossible to see all of the choices.

[image]

Can one be added?

Comment: Clearly you just need a bigger monitor

Comment: I guess they [took me too seriously](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/431376#431376).

Comment: @Michael: That's not the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Man, look at all those sites. Where did those come from? Clearly this is the Area 51 team's fault; they're producing too many sites.

I have assigned this bug to them, but since it might take a while for them to fix this, I've worked around it by making the site-chooser popup better at handling larger numbers of sites.